# models seem to stack up after clicking them with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This problem is going to be hard for me to explain but I will try my best.

When a user clicks a `UserView` it uses the same model to show a more detailed `ProfileView`

If the user clicks on more than one `UserView` and then decides to click on the chat button that is on each `ProfileView`. Every model that the user has clicked on in the is outputted

So say I have clicked 3 profiles and then I click on the chat button it will output this to the console.

```
"start chat with >" model1
"start chat with >" model2
"start chat with >" model3
```

I only want the user that was last clicked on...

**Can anyone explain to my why these models are stacking up?**

*Here is the code that you might need.*
UserView which represents each model in my collection.

```
var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'user',
    template: $('#tUser').html(),
    events: {
        'click' : 'clicked'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var user = _.template(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
        //this.el.html(user);
        var show = this.$el.html(user); 
        $('#users').append(show);
        return this;
    },

    clicked: function() {
        new ProfileView({model: this.model});
    }
});
```

As you can see I have set up a click event when a UserView is clicked and then it instantiates a ProfileView using the current model.

```
var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#profiles',
    template: $('#tProfile').html(),

    events: {
        'click .chat' : 'startChat'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        console.log('profile', this.model.toJSON());
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var user = this.model.toJSON();
        var profile = _.template(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
        var show = this.$el.html(profile);
        return this;
    },

    startChat: function() {
        console.log("start chat with", this.model.toJSON());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you plan on having more than one profile view visible on the screen at any given time, you should convert your profileView into a singleton.

Your UserView first checks if it has an assigned profile, and simply updates the model if so:

```
var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'user',
    template: $('#tUser').html(),
    events: {
        'click' : 'clicked'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var user = _.template(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
        //this.el.html(user);
        var show = this.$el.html(user); 
        $('#users').append(show);
        return this;
    },

    clicked: function() {
        if (this.profileView){
            this.profileView.unrender();
            this.profileView.model = this.model;
        } else {
            this.profileView = new ProfileView({model: this.model});
        }
        this.profileView.render();
    }
});
```

ProfileView no longer renders on instantiation:

```
var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#profiles',
    template: $('#tProfile').html(),

    events: {
        'click .chat' : 'startChat'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        console.log('profile', this.model.toJSON());
    },

    render: function() {
        var user = this.model.toJSON();
        var profile = _.template(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
        var show = this.$el.html(profile);
        return this;
    },

    startChat: function() {
        console.log("start chat with", this.model.toJSON());
    }
});
```

Comment: this still gives me the same problem, check out my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mR3fv/1/)  and see what I mean by using the console.

Comment: having looked at this answer again when I came up against the same problem. I now understand what you were doing here! I have now accepted this answer as the correct one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the problem. Each time your use clicks a profile, you are creating a new `ProfileView`, and when the view is created it binding a new view to the `click` event. Then when the user clicks the chat button, all three are rendering.

It seems odd, though, as usually click events are scoped to the view that bound to them.

The first thing I'd try is keeping a reference to your `ProfileView` in the `UserView` and zeroing it out each time you call `UserView.clicked`.

If you can repro this in a jsFiddle I can help you solve it. It's hard to spot the problem with what you have here, since the templates are omitted.

EDIT: Thanks for posting the Fiddle. I was able to figure out the issue, and I forked your Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/VVyH5/1/).

The problem was scope related, as I suspected, as the click events weren't behaving as I was expecting. You were setting `el` manually to the `<div id='profiles'></div>`. This is not recommended, as I learned recently. Each new `ProfileView` was getting bound to click events within this `el`, so as you created more zombie views (they were hanging around in the background) they were all responding to this overly broad scoped click event.

Here's the updated section of code:

```
var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // deleted el property
    render: function() {
        var anchor = $('#profiles');
        anchor.html("");
        var profile = _.template(this.template, this.model);
        this.$el.html(profile);
        anchor.append(this.$el.html(profile));
        return this;
    }

});
```

This is not the most elegant way to solve the problem, but it gets the job done. First I deleted the manual setter for `el`. Instead I selected and cleared out the `#profiles` div in the `render` method. Backbone creates its own `el`, which in this case is just a `div`. I then appended that to the anchor element.

While the immediate problem is solved, there are likely some other issues that will crop up later. Those views that you're repeatedly creating are probably hanging around, which will add up to a memory leak later. You're off to a good start, though!